# How can I remove Windows 10 from dual boot with elementary os

Tags: dual-boot

I used eOS quite a long time now and I'm very satisfied with it. I installed eOS alongside with W10 but want to get rid of W10 now. Both OS are installed on separate hdds.
Am I doing it right to use gparted and just delete the drive which holds the W10 installation? How can I update the GRUB loader in order to directly boot into eOS?

I hope you guys can help on this as I only found links on the internet how to remove eOS from dual boot.

Thank you,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type in terminal: sudo update-grub 
It should find only the Elementary.

Comment: Additionally read https://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-do-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu